# Generating first n prime numbers using dynamic programming

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

How can I generate first n prime numbers using dynamic programming ? (Code is not required just the concept would be enough)

Comment: Why was the question down-voted? This is a good question. Use Sieve's method, one will have to predetermine the range of the prime number, while it is not obvious to calculate the range.

Answer (score 2):

We can use Memoization technique for generating prime numbers using dynamic programing. You can write a function which accepts the number to be checked(say x) for primality and another parameter which accepts divisor(say the variable is i). Inside the function check for the conditions like i==1 then return 1 and x%i==0 then return 0 and again call the function recursivly with decrementing i and the result shoiud be stored in to an array.

Comment: What's the time complexity of this compared to sieve method?

Answer (score 2):

If you will google it, you will find the solution very easily:
BTW solution is 
Use method described here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes